# Ruby trouble with if, hash, block, or push

Tags: ruby, if-statement, hash, push, block

What I expect my code to do:
print out

```
{ "pivot0"=>5, "left0"=>[5,0,1,2,3,4], "right0"=>[6,7,8,9] }
```

What my code does: print out `{ "pivot0"=>5}`

I've used print to try to debug. Both `hash["left0"]` and `hash["right0"]` return [0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]. Yet neither keys are showing up at all inside hash.  And even if they did show up, they don't have the right numbers in them.  What am I not understanding?  As you can tell by the title, I don't even know what is causing the problem.  Trying to write similar code with any one of those factors removed (if, hash, block, or push) seems to give me expected results, so I'm thoroughly confused.

```
source = [5,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]

hash = Hash.new([])

l=0

hash['pivot' + l.to_s] = source[0]

source.each_with_index do |e, i|
    if i > 0
        if e <= hash['pivot' + l.to_s]
            puts "hit left on #{e}"
            hash['left'+l.to_s] << e
        else
          puts "hit right on #{e}"
            hash['right'+l.to_s] << e
        end
    end

end

print hash
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is the way you are constructing your `hash` object, and assuming that default value of empty array will be automatically assigned to a key on first access.

As the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) mentions,

> If obj is specified, this single object will be used for all default
>   values

In your case, the statement like below

```
hash['left'+l.to_s] << e
```

is effectively below code:

```
an_array = hash['left'+l.to_s]
an_array << e
```

This is not what you might have intended. You need to explicitly update the key's value in hash.

As you update a temporary array, its value is never inserted into hash.
You should be doing:

```
hash['left'+l.to_s] = hash['left'+l.to_s] << e
```

---

Or Alternatively, you can use constructor like below and you should get desired output with rest of code unchanged.

```
hash = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
```

Here, whenever a key is accessed for first time and it has no value associated with it, then the block `{|hash, key| hash[key] = [] }` will be executed - which basically assign an empty array value for that key.

---

Or you could use simple hash initialiser `{}` and handle `nil` values, as shown below:

```
source = [5,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]

hash = {}
l = 0

hash['pivot' + l.to_s] = source[0]

source.each_with_index do |e, i|
    if i > 0
        if e <= hash['pivot' + l.to_s]
            hash['left'+l.to_s] = (hash['left'+l.to_s] || []) << e
        else
            hash['right'+l.to_s] = (hash['right'+l.to_s] || []) << e
        end
    end
end

print hash
#=> {"pivot0"=>5, "left0"=>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], "right0"=>[6, 7, 8, 9]}
```

Expression like `(hash['left'+l.to_s] || [])` returns first operand if its not `nil`, else returns the value of second operand, which in this case happens to be an empty array.

Comment: What an unbelievably fantastic answer.  You've explained everything so well that even a rookie like me can't fail to understand any part of it!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity:

```
src = [5,0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9]
%i(pivot left right).zip(
  [pivot = src.first, *src.partition { |e| e <= pivot }]
).to_h
#⇒ "{:pivot=>5, :left=>[5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], :right=>[6, 7, 8, 9]}"
```